# +/- columns names collapse and sum

Tags: r, sum

I need to collapse "+/-" columns names into one column name and add counts. Here is an example of the dataset.

```
data <- as.data.frame(c("+A","-A","+A","-A", "+A","+A","-B","+B","-B", "C","C"))
colnames(data) <- "class"

table(data$class)
-A -B +A +B  C 
 2  2  4  1  2
```

I would like to collapse those -/+ col names into no sign column names and add them up.

The desired dataset should look like below:

```
A   B   C
6   3   2
```

Sometimes these +/- variables might be missing or category "C" might be missing too. How can I add them up even though I have some missing categories?

Any thoughts?

Comment: Do NOT use `class` as a column name. It an essential R function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I modified your example, to cover certain cases mentioned in your post. Let's say you'll have only 3 categories in your data, we can extract characters `A-C`, convert it into `factor` with 3 levels and then use `table`. In this case, we do not have any entry for category `"C"`, converting to `factor` with `levels` helps to keep the count even when a category is absent.

```
data <- data.frame(col = c("+A","A","+A","-A","+A","+A","-B","+B","-B"))

table(factor(sub(".*([A-C]).*", "\\1", data$col), levels = LETTERS[1:3]))
#A B C 
#6 3 0
```

If there are more than 3 categories present in the data, we can adjust the regex and `levels` in `factor` accordingly.

Answer (score 5):

```
table(gsub("\\W", "", data$class))

A B C 
6 3 2
```

This gives you output of class `table`. If this is not sufficient, you might wrap it in `as.data.frame(t(c(x)))` to have the same output, but of class `data.frame`, like this:

```
as.data.frame(t(c(table(gsub("\\W", "", data$class)))))
```